# Load an image once and use it multiple times in different places?

Tags: jquery, variables

Here's what I think I want to do but I can't wrap my head around the right way to do it.

So I load a bunch of images into variables (think digital clock)...

```
var digit0 = "images/d0.png";
var digit1 = "images/d1.png";
var digit2 = "images/d2.png";
var digit3 = "images/d3.png";
var digit4 = "images/d4.png";
var digit5 = "images/d5.png";
var digit6 = "images/d6.png";
var digit7 = "images/d7.png";
var digit8 = "images/d8.png";
var digit9 = "images/d9.png";
```

Then in a loop I try to load those images into a div...

```
//SKIP A BUNCH OF TIMER CODE THAT WORKS AND GIVES ME "seconds".

var secondDigit = "digit"+(seconds.toString()).substr(1,1);
//Trying to make a string that refers to the matching variable above.

$("#d1").html('<img src="'+digit0+'" />');        //-- THIS ONE WORKS 
$("#d2").html('<img src="'+secondDigit+'" />');   //-- THIS ONE DOESN'T
```

Edit: So using this method, does it hit the server every time? If so, that's not what I want. I want to save the images once so I can use them over and over without hitting the server every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your images will be cached by the browser, so no worries there.

---

Use an actual array instead of an array (:P) of variables:

```
var digits [
    "images/d0.png",
    "images/d1.png",
    "images/d2.png",
    "images/d3.png",
    "images/d4.png",
    "images/d5.png",
    "images/d6.png",
    "images/d7.png",
    "images/d8.png",
    "images/d9.png"
];

var secondDigit = seconds.toString().substr(1,1);

$("#d2").html('<img src="' + digits[secondDigit] + '" />');
```

Comment: That makes sense! But that will hit the server every time, correct? Is there a way to get the images one time and use them over and over?

Comment: @Layne - Nope. The images will be cached by the browser. For better performance, you shouldn't be replacing those images, but updating their `src`.

Comment: "updating their src" That's what I'd be doing with "$("#d2").html('<img src="' + digits[secondDigit] + '" />');" correct?

Comment: @Layne - Nope. You're *replacing* those images. Here's a [non-functioning] fiddle with some sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/5KFW3/

Comment: Is this comparable? $("#d2 img").attr("src", digits[firstDigit]); or does that also replace instead of update?

Comment: @Layne - It is comparable, but it queries the DOM on every tick. In the fiddle there I showed you how to cache a reference to the image.